# Delete item with Button click

Tags: android-studio, sql-delete

In my `MainActivity` I want my button to delete all items in my view list. Unfortunately, all the solutions I found here won't help me. If I click on the Button "Clear All" it deletes every item in my list, but the items are still saved in my Database.

I am totally new to Android Studio, so I don´t know how to write my code that it will work the way I want it.

This is my MainActivity:

```
package com.vorlesung.iubh.todo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHepler myDB;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    ListView myToDoList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    SparseBooleanArray selectedItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button addToDo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addToDo);
        Button clearAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearALL);
        Button editSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editSelected);
        Button clearDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearDone);

        myToDoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myToDoList);
        myDB = new DatabaseHepler(this);

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();

        if (data.getCount() == 0)
            Toast.makeText(this, "The Database was empty",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                list.add(data.getString(1));
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
                myToDoList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClickaddToDo(View button) {
        Intent newToDo = new Intent(this, AddToDo.class);
        startActivity(newToDo);
    }

    // With this onClick I want to delete all Items from my List.
    public void onClickaclearALL(View button) {
        list.clear();
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And this is my DataBase:

```
package com.vorlesung.iubh.todo;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHepler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myList.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "myList_Data";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "ITEM1";

    public DatabaseHepler(Context context){super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "ITEM1 TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    }

    public boolean addData(String item1) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item1);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }

    public void deleteRow() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+ COL2, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

### Edit

There are the errors which are shown in my log File:

```
2018-12-23 10:16:05.627 21957-21973/com.vorlesung.iubh.todo E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2018-12-23 10:16:05.627 21957-21973/com.vorlesung.iubh.todo E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
2018-12-23 10:16:05.628 21957-21973/com.vorlesung.iubh.todo E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
2018-12-23 10:17:26.766 21957-21957/com.vorlesung.iubh.todo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.vorlesung.iubh.todo, PID: 21957
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1656)
    at com.vorlesung.iubh.todo.DatabaseHepler.deleteAllRow(DatabaseHepler.java:51)
    at com.vorlesung.iubh.todo.MainActivity.onClickaclearALL(MainActivity.java:59)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: you only cleared the list, but never called deleteRow ....

Comment: @Jacob yeah i know that, but i don´t know where i have to call it, or how :( do i have to call it in my MainActivity or in my DataBase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function in **DatabaseHepler**, to delete all the elements from table.

In DatabaseHepler class Need to write this function.

```
public void deleteAllRow() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
}
```

In your main activity need to write this code:

```
// With this onClick I want to delete all Items from my List.
public void onClickaclearALL(View button) {
    list.clear();
    myDB.deleteAllRow(); // this will delete all data from the table.
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This will help for you.

Comment: now the app stops if i click on the "Clear All" Button

Comment: 2018-12-23 10:12:56.234 21718-21718/com.vorlesung.iubh.todo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vorlesung.iubh.todo, PID: 21718
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Comment: not sure if this is the right one, but this is shown when i click on the button

Comment: please update the function deleteAllRow() in your code as above.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you .. now it works fine for me. Thanks a lot and happy christmas :D

Answer (score 1):

1. You should delete from the database first and then update the list.
2. Don't perform database actions in main thread and use AsyncTask.

In your code, you should have two AsyncTasks: one for retrieve this list and the other for clearing the list.

For example, you can have this in your MainActivity

```
private class DeleteItemsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private Context mContext;

        DeleteItemsAsyncTask(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            myDB.deleteRow();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
            list.clear();
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Then you onclick should be

```
// With this onClick I want to delete all Items from my List.
public void onClickaclearALL(View button) {
    new DeleteItemsAsyncTask(this).execute();
}
```

Similarly, you should do the same for listing the data.